# Lectura de ficheros en C

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de realizar un programa el cual el contenido de un archivo y relacione su contenido a una estructura ya que posee dos campos que quiero guardar, el primer campo que contiene el carácter y el segundo campo que contiene el código de ese carácter. Por ejemplo:

P:00
N:01
Z:10

Mi problema esta en que el programa debe guardar cualquier tipo de caracter, incluso el caracter de fin de linea (\n), en ese caso al ser dos se complica todo. En estos momentos hago la lectura con "fscanf(diccionario, "%c:%s", letra, codigo);" pero en el caso anteriormente indicado, me lee el "\" como un caracter y la "n" como otro distinto. 
Pense en leer caracter a caracter pero no encuentro la manera de relacionarlo despues con la estructura. Si podrian ayudarme con alguna idea se los agradeceria.
Les dejo el codigo que uso actualmente:

```
void guarda_diccionario(char diccionariotxt[20]){
    int i=0, nro_elementos=0;
    FILE * diccionario;

    diccionario = fopen(diccionariotxt, "r");       //Abrimos el diccionario para asignar cada campo a la estructura.
    if(!diccionario){
        printf("Archivo invalido...\n");
        return;
    }

    if(diccionario != NULL){
        while(!feof(diccionario)){          //Empieza a guardar cada campo.
            fscanf(diccionario, "%c:%s", &nodo[nro_elementos].letra,&nodo[nro_elementos].codigo);
            nro_elementos++;
        }
    fclose(diccionario);
    }
}
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de que tengas claro lo que es un "caracter". De todas maneras, antes de ponerte a programar deberías responder(nos) una pregunta como la siguiente: supon que el fichero va a contener los datos correspondientes al caracter 'a' y al '\n' . ¿cuántos bytes tendría el archivo? ¿podrías escribirnos el contenido de ese fichero, byte por byte (digamos, en hexadecimal)?

Answer (score 2):

> Mi problema esta en que el programa debe guardar cualquier tipo de caracter

Y ese, es un problema terrible. Sobre todo teniendo en cuenta que aparentemente cada uno de los caracteres tiene significado semántico.

[leonbloy](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2008/leonbloy) ha apuntado en la dirección correcta: *no tienes claro lo que es un caracter*. [Veamos la tabla de caracteres](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII):
[image: Tabla ASCII (American Standard Code for Information Interchange)]
Podemos ver que existe un caracter para el [retorno de carro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retorno_de_carro) cuyo código es el `10` decimal (`0a` hexadecimal o `00001010` binario). No es posible expresar dicho caracter directamente en el código pues produce un error de compilación, como se ve aquí:

```
char frase[] = "En un lugar de La Mancha
de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme";
```

El código anterior provoca error de compilación pues el compilador considera que la instrución finaliza tras `"La Mancha"`, es decir: justo en el retorno de carro... el compilador ve una instrucción que ni finaliza en punto y coma (`;`) ni cierra la cadena de texto con el caracter de cierre (`"`).

Dado que no se puede escribir un retorno de carro literalmente en la cadena de texto, hay que buscar una manera de escribirlo sin que afecte a cómo el compilador interpretará el código... para eso se *inventaron* las [secuencias de escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence). Tanto en [c](/questions/tagged/c) como en otros lenguajes de su familia, la secuencia de escape empieza por la barra `\` seguida del código del caracter que se quiera escribir, así pues el retorno de carro es el `\n` que ya conoces, la n pertenece a "nueva línea", con ello podemos corregir el error anterior:

```
char frase[] = "En un lugar de La Mancha\nde cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme";
```

Pero no debemos confundir la secuencia de escape con una secuencia de caracteres; el `\n` en la cadena de texto de ejemplo es un sólo caracter (el caracter de retorno de carro) no una secuencia de dos caracteres (la barra `\` y la ene `n`).

---

Ahora volvamos a tu archivo de texto, supongamos que su contenido es el siguiente:

> ```
> P:00 N:01 Z:10 \n:11
> ```

Esto son 20 caracteres (bytes):

```
byte        |00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|
caracter    | P| :| 0| 0|  | N| :| 0| 1|  | Z| :| 1| 0|  | \| n| :| 1| 1|
hexadecimal |50|3a|30|30|20|4e|3a|30|31|20|5a|3a|31|30|20|5c|6e|3a|31|31|
```

Si quieres un retorno de carro debes escribirlo explícitamente, pues al contrario que en un código fuente de C no va a afectar a la compilación:

> ```
> P:00 N:01 Z:10 
> :11
> ```

Esto son 19 caracteres (bytes):

```
byte        |00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|
caracter    | P| :| 0| 0|  | N| :| 0| 1|  | Z| :| 1| 0|  |\n| :| 1| 1|
hexadecimal |50|3a|30|30|20|4e|3a|30|31|20|5a|3a|31|30|20|0a|3a|31|31|
```